# Database in java

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp

I am looking for a java frame work or environment to fasten up the process of creating tables in the database and the corresponding data classes and web pages...

So I am basically looking for some way faster than writing the sql commands to build up a database tables and then implement data classes to use them in queries and then creating JSP pages to deal with the data...

[My environment setup: JAVA, Ubuntu, Apache-Tomcat, mySQL]

Any suggestions??

Comment: Try to search for "Java ORM" (Object-relational mapping), tons of them out there.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some names to get you started:

```
JPA - Java Persistence API  
Hibernate - JPA implementation. Especially good for use with J2EE  
EclipseLink - Non J2EE implementation of JPA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Java) (i.e. Hibernate) but I would recommend it rather for complex and extensively linked tables where it's worth it.

I like using [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html). It's very fast, simple to use and you have complete control over the whole process. It's a little bit low level compared to ORM frameworks but for simple databases it's great. You can see how it looks like [in this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) and you can also read [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-jdbcdaosupport-examples/), where JdbcTemplate is compared to standard Java access

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans IDE has nice support; generating JPA Entity classes from a DB, and vice versa generating tables from entity classes. Furthermore with fine tutorials.